# Chrome opens webpage and closes immediately using Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I want to write java web automation code with selenium. Although I have added Chrome.exe to my project, the page I want does not open when I run it. It closes immediately and I don't get any errors.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As what shown in the picture , the driver version is not match with the browser version, I think the solution is :
Update your chrome browser or download the right verion of the driver from the below url :
https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/home

Answer (score 0):

As per the snapshot your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- Your *JDK* version ***1.8.0_201*** is old and ancient.
- You are using *chromedriver=97.0.4692.36*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=97.0.4692.36*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/97.0.4692.36/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome version 97**

- You are using *chrome=96.0.4664.110*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v96.0.4664.45*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/87.0.4280.20/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome version 96**

So there is a clear mismatch between *chrome=96.0.4664.110* and the *chromedriver=97.0.4692.36*

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *JDK* is upgraded to current levels [JDK 8u301](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html).
- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current released [Version 3.141.59](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v96.0.4664.45](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/87.0.4280.20/) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 96.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v96.0.4664.45 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/87.0.4280.20/notes.txt)).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are using compatible driver version with the browser you are are automating.
As per your image diver is 96 version and chrome is 97 version so issue is happening